# iPhone 5s not working for iOS development with iOS 11.0.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am working on a camera app in Swift. Because it is a camera app I have to use the iPhone to run versions of the software. I recently upgraded to iOS 11.0.2 on the iPhone 5s. Now when I try to run the app on the phone I get the following message "This iPhone 5s (Model A1453, A1533) is running iOS 11.0.2 (15A421), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode."  and the software will not load. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: My iPhone is working fine with XCode 9.0. I have iPhone 5s with iOS11.0.2

Answer (score 2):

You should update your Xcode to Xcode 9. Xcode 8 will not compile for iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

Update your xcode to xcode 9. This issue is because of the mismatch version of xcode and your device. To run the app on IOS 11 you must have xcode 9.

Answer (score -1):

Install the xcode 9 because the iOS 11 is only supported run using xcode 9. The previous xcode couldn't run in iOS 11

Answer (score -3):

Please make sure your app is 64bit. Also check https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=06282017b

Comment: The issue in this question is about a mismatch between the version of iOS on the device and the version of Xcode. It has nothing to do with any specific app and certainly not anything to do with whether the app is 64-bit enabled or not.